# need gcc 4.1.2 on fedora

Tags: gcc, g++, version, fedora

We have a problem with actually running a plugins in softimage. The thing is we compile it, there's no error but Softimage cannot run it.

So, our plan right now is to recompile it on gcc-4.1.2 but we don't know how to install a previous version. Because Softimage is actually recommanding this version (http://softimage.wiki.softimage.com/sdkdocs/cpp_setup_CompilingPlugins.htm).

So, any idea how to install and use it ?

A simple solution if possible.

Thanks

W

UPDATE:

Or is it possible to compile by specifying the version of the compiler that we want to use ? Something like gcc --compiler-version=4.1.2 test.cpp ? So this way, it will be compatible with with Softimage and we won't need a VM to manage to compile all of this!

If you can do this on Ubuntu, it might be a great!

Answer (score 0):

Can it not find the libraries?

Maybe configure gcc like this (assuming your building gcc from scratch):

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2

Then when you run your application you'll need:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2/lib64:/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH your_app

Or make some other arrangements for making sure your library path contains the libraries.

I should have asked first: where are you getting gcc-4.1.2?  Are you building it or do you have an install package somewhere?  If the latter, dou you know where the libraries are installed?

Comment: Humm! I always tried to find it by using yum... but from the RPM, there was a couple of dependencies that we didn't have too!